# Vim - Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitOptions, arpeggio#load, pathogen#infect, pathogen#helptags

Tags: vim, pathogen

I recently installed yadr and oh-my-zsh onto my MacBook Air, after doing so when I try to use `vim` using iTerm2 (also happens on the Terminal app) I get some errors.

When I try to do `vim test.c` (or open any existing file for example, easymotion.vim), the following errors will come up.

```
Error detected while processing /Users/"myusername"/.yadr/vim/plugin/settings/easymoti
on.vim:
line   14:
E117: Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitOptions
Error detected while processing /Users/"myusername"/.yadr/vim/plugin/settings/yadr-key
map.vim:
line    2:
E117: Unknown function: arpeggio#load
```

When I press enter I'll enter the normal vim editor screen. After I :q! to exit the vim editor the following errors will come up.

```
Error detected while processing /Users/"myusername"/.vimrc:
line   16:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
line   17:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#helptags
```

Comment: It appears that for some reason your `.vim` folder was moved to `.yadr/vim`, try moving it back to `~/"yourusername"/.vim`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I have no idea why the structure is like that (obviously because of YADR). However, you shouldn't be using a distribution, it is bad practice and it causes unnecessary errors (like this one). And also they usually have strange and confusing structures...

Comment: Drop that stupid distribution. Like all its friends, it hides too many functionalities and makes customizing/debugging an unecessary complex nightmare. If you are interested in some of the plugins, install them manually or via pathogen/vundle/other plugin/runtimepath manager. If you are interested in some of the custom mappings, consult the documentation and make sure that you understand what they do before copying them to *your own* `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I can only suggest what @romainl already said. It might seem convenient at first, but only until it breaks. Your actual problem wasn't too hard to fix in the end, but without building your own vimrc and choosing your own plugins (and reading their documentation), that can happen again and again, because you most probably can't know (without understanding the sources) what magic spells these distributions cast. :-)